# Error from server (NotFound): services "argocd-server" not found. Anyone else encountering this error?

Tags: argocd

So every time I try to port forward I keep getting this error. I went to other stack overflow questions and I can't seem to solve it.

I tried to create the argocd-server but gave up halfway through. I also looked at what was actually installed and it seems like the argocd-server was never installed to begin with. Even though I followed the instructions from the ArgoCD website. https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you use the first alternative in the first step instead of "core"

`kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml`